# messages can't sent from outbox of Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have configured outlook 2010 in domain. as in domain system there is no need to configure outlook as it directly access account from computer in Domain system.
I have sent many emails, but from this morning I am unable to send email as sent email get stuck in outbox folder and even click on send/receive option the emails in the outbox remain as it is. I don't know what problem arise. as I checked my internet connection also and try to restart Outlook as well as computer but no effect at all. please give me solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should open the Send/Receive progress window, and verify there are no errors listed on the Errors tab. However, most of the time I see this issue, it's because "Do Not Deliver Before..." has been turned on.

1. Go to your Outbox.
2. Double click on one of the emails that won't send.
3. Verify "Delay Delivery" is not highlighted in the More options group.
4. Click on the More Options button, and triple verify that *Do not delivery before..* is not checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Message stuck in Outbox could be caused by several factors. Try following MS official article first to troubleshoot the issue:

[My messages won't send](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/my-messages-won-t-send-97748418-bbd5-4743-a05b-581f22a466dd)